# How To Make A Function That Links To a Certain File In WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Ok, so im working on a theme that I want to have different styles and php files depending on which design the user has chosen. How would I do this? The best example I can give is having a `get_template_part` function that changes directory based on the users selection of design. Heres my idea of how the code would kinda look.

```
<?php /*custom_function*/(/*Global Path variable which changes*/, '/filename') ?>
```

The x theme has like stacks I think which might be a similar idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this in the function.php: (just an example)

```
     <?php
       define("DESIGN", "flat");
        if(DESIGN == "flat"){
         add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'asd_scripts' );
       }elseif(DESIGN == "notflat"){
          // other  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '...' );
        }
       function asd_scripts() {
       // load bootstrap js
       wp_enqueue_script('asd-bootstrapjs',   get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery') );
       }
     ?>
```

Comment: I dont think you understand what I mean, I mean a function that calls a certain file directory depending on the choice of design selected. So for example if I select the design to be flat ui it will go to Framework/js(or css, php)/flat.js but if i select the design to be metro ui it will go to Framework/js(or css, php)/metro.js.    **Does this make it clearer?**

Comment: surely if I did $Path = '/Framework/Js/Flatui'; and then made a function which I wouldnt know how to code, and then did function($Path . 'something.css');

Comment: my best example is to look at theme x

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [theme customization api](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API) to achieve this. For example you would use the [`customize_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_register) hook:

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize )
{
   //All your sections, settings, and controls will be added here
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

This hook allows you access to the `$wp_customize` object.

There are existing [examples](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_register#Examples) in the WordPress docs, this should get you started with what you would like to do.

Comment: Ok but how would I get the specified file? I was thinking of something like for example:    mytheme_customize_register( GLOBALVAR_PATH, 'flatui');?

Comment: this doesn’t save any changes in the actual theme files, or the template files or the stylesheet. When the website is rendered, WordPress outputs inline CSS generated by the Theme Customizer to the '<head>', which overrides the stylesheet. You can find a full tutorial for this [over here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/05/the-wordpress-theme-customizer-a-developers-guide/)

Comment: ik but I just want to get a function that can let the user change the code rapidly of my theme to diversify it, it doesnt have to be changed through the customizer, possibly the theme settings page?

Comment: I understand, what I can suggest is that you perhaps try a few of the options you have been provided, there are a lot of code samples etc. Unfortunately we cannot write these functions for you as we are not directly working with your theme.  However we will be here to help when you have tried some of the options and get stuck :-)

Comment: ok but I really am stuck, ive done everything that I can do without needing this

Comment: You can also visit http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ for some excellent wordpress help, its stack overflow for wordpress! (plenty of experts)